# How to move widgets around in wordpress?

Tags: search, widget

I'd like to place the search input field in the top menu bar (like so http://4buzz.org/ for my wp version of that http://wp.4buzz.org/ ), but so far I haven't been able to find how to move the widgets around. As I'm novice to PHP, if there are some step by step guides on how to do that, can you please share some of those or point me in some right direction?

Thank you,

Xeen

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: place `<?php get_search_form(); ?>` in the theme whereever you want the widget to be.